# nginx configuration with multiple location blocks

Tags: php, nginx, nginx-location

I'm trying to configure nginx to serve 2 different php scripts from 2 different location. The configuration is as follows.

1. I have a Laravel installation which resides in `/home/hamed/laravel` in which its `public` directory should be served.
2. I have a Wordpress installation in `/home/hamed/www/blog`.

And this is my `nginx` configuration:

```
server {
        listen  443 ssl;
        server_name example.com www.example.com;

        #root /home/hamed/laravel/public;

        index index.html index.htm index.php;

        ssl_certificate /root/hamed/ssl.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /root/hamed/ssl.key;

        location /blog {
                root /home/hamed/www/blog;
                try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php?do=$request_uri;
        }

        location / {
                root /home/hamed/laravel/public;
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$request_uri;
        }
        error_page 404 /404.html;
        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
                root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.hamed.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }

}
```

The problem is when trying to access the wordpress section by calling `example.com/blog` still the the laravel installtion takes over the request.

Now I have tried replacing `root` directive inside `location` blocks with `alias` to no avail.

According to [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-nginx-server-and-location-block-selection-algorithms) having the `index` directive or `try_files` inside `location` triggers an internal redirect which I suspect causes this behavior.

Would someone please help me figure this out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to @RichardSmith I finally managed to create the right configuration. Here is the final working config. I had to use the combination of nested `location` blocks and an inverse regex match for it to work.

```
server {
    listen  443 ssl;
        server_name example.com;
        root /home/hamed/laravel/public;

#        index index.html index.htm index.php;

        ssl_certificate /root/hamed/ssl.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /root/hamed/ssl.key;

        location ~ ^/blog(.*)$ {
        index index.php;
        root /home/hamed/www/;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php?do=$request_uri;

        location ~ \.php$ {
                    try_files $uri =404;
                    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                    #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.hamed.sock;
                    fastcgi_index index.php;
                    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                    include fastcgi_params;
            }

        }

    location ~ ^((?!\/blog).)*$ { #this regex is to match anything but `/blog`
        index index.php;
                root /home/hamed/laravel/public;
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$request_uri;
        location ~ \.php$ {
                    try_files $uri =404;
                    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                    #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.hamed.sock;
                    fastcgi_index index.php;
                    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                    include fastcgi_params;
            }
        }


        error_page 404 /404.html;
        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
                root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        }


}
```

Answer (score 8):

The problem is that `location ~ \.php$ { ... }` is responsible for handling all of your php scripts, which are divided across two different roots.

One approach is to use a common `root` for the `server` container and perform internal rewrites within each prefix location block. Something like:

```
location /blog {
  rewrite ^(.*\.php)$ /www$1 last;
  ...
}
location / {
  rewrite ^(.*\.php)$ /laravel/public$1 last;
  ...
}
location ~ \.php$ {
  internal;
  root /home/hamed;
  ...
}
```

The above should work (but I have not tested it with your scenario).

The second approach is to use nested location blocks. The `location ~ \.php$ { ... }` block is then replicated in each application's location block. Something like:

```
location /blog {
  root /home/hamed/www;
  ...
  location ~ \.php$ {
    ...
  }
}
location / {
  root /home/hamed/laravel/public;
  ...
  location ~ \.php$ {
    ...
  }
}
```

Now that one has been tested to work.

Comment: Thanks, although your solution didn't actually work, it led me to figure the correct solution which I will post shortly here.

Comment: There was a typo in my second approach: `root /home/hamed/www/blog;` should be `root /home/hamed/www;`. Perhaps that's why it didn't work. I've fixed it anyway.