# Nginx - Changing the server root make location root not working

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I'm trying to setup phpmyadmin on my domain, and for some reason, I can't have the server root I want.

This doesn't work (404 on example.com/phpmyadmin without anything in the logs):

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
    client_max_body_size 300m;
    root /var/www/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name example.com;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location /phpmyadmin/ {
        root /var/www/admin/;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

But if I change the server root to /usr/share/nginx/html it works...

Do you have any idea of what is happening?
Thank you for reading me.

Answer (score 2):

Ok I fixed it, thanks to this post : [nginx configuration with multiple location blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34082831/nginx-configuration-with-multiple-location-blocks?rq=1)

The reason was the ~ location for php files...

So here is the working code :

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
    client_max_body_size 300m;
    root /var/www/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name example.com;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location /phpmyadmin/ {
        root /var/www/admin/;
        location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
        }
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }


}
```